# Changing cv joint on Expedition

Tags: ford, expedition, cv-joint

When changing cv joint should we replace the seal? 
Right now the front diff to the first rubber of cv joint is wet/has diff oil on it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is showing signs of failing so do it while the opportunity is there - otherwise you pay for labor twice to do it later...